# Get custom taxonomy name from custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I want to retrieve the category assigned to a custom post type.

The problem is, I don't know in advance what post-type (hence, what post-category) I will get. I have 5 custom post types, each with a custom taxonomy.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a list of term names of the custom post type im currently on in single.php](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168114/how-to-get-a-list-of-term-names-of-the-custom-post-type-im-currently-on-in-singl)

Answer (score 0):

**Blueprint**

1. Get all taxonomies.
2. Loop through them.
3. Get terms for current post.

**Code**

```
// Suppose you already have $post
foreach ( get_object_taxonomies( $post ) as $taxonomy ) {
    foreach ( get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy ) as $term ) {
        // Do whatever you'd like with $term
        echo $term->name;
    }
}
```

**References**

- [get_object_taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies)
- [get_the_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)