# Get custom taxonomy name (not the term) in custom post

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Is it possible, within the loop (or given the post ID) to retrieve the name/slug of  the main custom taxonomy of a custom post?

What I really need is the taxonomy term, and that one I can find it with:

```
wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy-name);
```

but in order to do it I need to provide the taxonomy name. What if I don't know it in advance?

Any idea?

Comment: If you need to get and display the post terms without knowing the taxonomy, look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/168163/31545) I have recently done

Answer (score 1):

I have found an hopefully elegant solution

```
$taxonomy_names = get_object_taxonomies( $post, 'objects' );
foreach ($taxonomy_names as $tax) {
    if ($tax->query_var != 'tag') { 
    // needed because $taxonomy names containes more than one query_var
        $current_tax_name_slug = $tax->query_var;
    }
}
```

This one works for me